# Turning words into uppercase in C

Tags: c

I have this problem from school, (below is my code), i can turn the characters into uppeercase, but i dont know how to stop getting input, normally my teacher would give something like "the input ends when it encounter '1'", but this time his test case is just normal text:

**the problem:**
Description
Given a TEXT, write a program that converts the TEXT to upper-case.

Example

Input
Hello John,

How are you?

Bye,

Output

HELLO JOHN,

HOW ARE YOU?

BYE,

**my code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    char c;
    while(1){
        scanf("%c", &c);
        if(c == EOF) break;
        else{
            c = toupper(c);
            printf("%c", c);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

my code proccesses uppercase request fine, but it never ends. Can you help me, thank you very much!

Comment: RTFM! You should read the documentation for `scanf` and `fgetc`. The latter returns the `EOF` constant, the former returns the number of conversion characters correctly processed or -1 for a read error. That is enough to explain why your program contains a never ending loop...

Comment: `scanf` is an overused function. It's not needed here. There are simpler functions to read characters from standard input. The `scanf` function is also too complicated for absolute beginners, IMO. Especially since most beginner material doesn't seem to teach how to use it properly. Proper use *must* check what `scanf` [*returns*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf#Return_value).

Comment: There are also other problems with comparing a `char` value with the `int` value `EOF`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`scanf` returns `EOF` rather than storing that value in the character value you've passed a pointer to.

```
int main(){
    char c;
    int result;
    while(1){
        result = scanf("%c", &c);
        if(result == EOF) break;
        else{
            c = toupper(c);
            printf("%c", c);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

You will not EOF until you type special keyboard key combination.

- Linux/Mac: CTRL-D
- Windows: CTRL-Z

Comment: Corner error: If `c` has a negative value (e.g. some non-ASCII character and `char` is _signed_), `toupper(c)` is _undefined behavior_ (UB).  Consider `unsigned char c;`.